# clearTimeout() not working properly inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following useEffect:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const closeFeedbackTimer = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('test')
    }, 5000)

    if (!finishedFeedbackOpen) {
      clearTimeout(closeFeedbackTimer)
    }
  }, [finishedFeedbackOpen])
```

And `finishedFeedbackOpen` is set to true/false with a function inside my component.

The problem is:  when `finishedFeedbackOpen` is set to `false`, the timeout is not cleared, even if entering the if condition.

Comment: How are you creating `finishedFeedbackOpen` are you using `useState(false)` or something like that?

Comment: Please share a [mcve]--the whole component with function definition, preferably as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/how-do-i-create-a-react-stack-snippet-with-jsx-support). Thanks.

Comment: yes, i'm using useState(false) @Dale

Comment: Where is finishedFeedbackOpen being set? My guess is that finishedFeedbackOpen is being set somehow and restarting the timeout again.

Comment: how is that, @illiteratewriter ?

Comment: i think that the timeout is not being restarted, as the log is only printed 1 time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the return function to clearTimeout inside useEffect. modify your code to something below

```
useEffect(() => {
    
    if (finishedFeedbackOpen) {
      const closeFeedbackTimer = setTimeout(() => {
         console.log('test')
       }, 5000)

      return ()=> clearTimeout(closeFeedbackTimer)
    }
  }, [finishedFeedbackOpen])
```

More info on it here: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#effects-with-cleanup